# Implementing custom gestures inside ant design components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angularjs, npm, antd

I use this component a lot inside my app, https://ant.design/components/transfer/

```
  <Transfer
   dataSource={mockData}
   titles={['Source', 'Target']}
   targetKeys={targetKeys}
   selectedKeys={selectedKeys}
   onChange={onChange}
   onSelectChange={onSelectChange}
   onScroll={onScroll}
   render={item => item.title}
/>
```

The problem is I want to implement custom feature such that It will select all items between click and shift click, or a drag to select all, currently the ant design API only supports select all, inverse which are not suitable for me because I have 100s of rows.

How would I approach this issue, are there any other npm packages I can use to get this done? I have never implemented stuff like keyboard shortcuts and features like this so I am looking for suggestions or even raw ideas.

Comment: Not an answer but I found an issue on their github that discusses your scenario .
Apparently keyboard events are not handled by the API yet; and generally it has been on their future plans for a couple of years now. I doubt this feature will be rolled out soon.
Here is the link for further info https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/14988

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ant Design Table Transfer: How to implement custom features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70977423/ant-design-table-transfer-how-to-implement-custom-features)